# Requesting facebook permissions on tab page

Tags: facebook

I have a simple task to do but i am unable to find a solution for my problem.

I have a facebook page tab. Now i want to get the email permission of a user accessing my app and then display his email address on the page tab directly.

I found a solution in the facebook documentation that gets the permission an then redirects to a given url. That works fine. But how can i redirect back to my page tab? if i try to enter the page tab url it just goes to an indefinite loop. (because the $code variable is not set it seems)

```
   <?php 

   $app_id = "APP_ID";
   $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
   $my_url = "REDIRECT_URL";

   session_start();
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=email" . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Mail: " . $user->email);
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript SDK as it is all client-side and you will have easier control over where and when things happen.  The login dialog can be a modal FB.login() and then call the FB.api() to get the user's email. See:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do it server side I suggest you use the facebook php sdk at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
it makes things a lot easier. hth.